# Changing a variable inside a function when any arrow key is pressed

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, signals

Iam new to c and gui in c . This is the problem I have. 
Both functions are working properly independently ,but snake_move function is not changing it's key value when I press the keys.The window widget is not even opening while execution.
If I dont call the snake move every thing is going fine ie key_event is working!! How do I change the code so that the key_val in the snake_call function changes when I press any arrow keys??

Thanks in advance

```
//Detects the key and puts the value to new
static gboolean
key_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventKey *event ,int* new) {
    if(strcmp(gdk_keyval_name (event->keyval),"Up")==0) {
        *new = 8;
        printf("%d\n",*new);
    } else if(strcmp(gdk_keyval_name (event->keyval),"Down")==0) {
        *new=2;
        printf("%d\n",*new);
    } else if(strcmp(gdk_keyval_name (event->keyval),"Right")==0) {
        *new=6;
        printf("%d\n",*new);
    } else if(strcmp(gdk_keyval_name (event->keyval),"Left")==0) {
        *new=4;
        printf("%d\n",*new);
    }
    return FALSE;
}
//Moves the snake by one bit in the direction specified by new (*new = 8 means up so on
void snake_loop(int**arr,int lenth,int*new,int*pos_x ,int *pos_y) {
    int x_pos,y_pos,key_value;
    x_pos=*pos_x ;y_pos =*pos_y;
    while(1) {
        key_value = *new;
        snake_move(arr ,&lenth ,key_value,&x_pos ,&y_pos);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should redesign your game logic: GTK+ is an event driven system so a loop such as the one in `snake_loop()` is a big no-no: the key event handling code will never be called because the execution is stuck in the loop that never ends. It might make sense to read up on Event Driven Programming in general first if the concept is new.

You should start the GTK+ mainloop (with `gtk_main()`) and put your code in short lived handler functions that get called based on system events. An example would be a timer event that happens e.g. once a second: The handler function for that timer event could then update the snake position. You can use [g_timeout_add_seconds()](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add-seconds) to setup the timer.

Alternatively you could have another thread for your game logic, but this is more difficult and nothing you've shown so far indicates you would need that.